# How to find ${\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} \sin(\frac{1}{t})}\,\mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$There was a hint in the book, use intregation by parts in this way: $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} \sin\frac{1}{t} \,\d t = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x}  t^2 \left(\frac{1}{t^2} \sin\frac{1}{t}\right)\,\d t.$$

When we integrate by parts we find this integral:

$$\int_0^{x} t\cos\frac{1}{t}\,\d t .$$

In every symbolic calculator it says is a special function and gives the value of the integral as $\mathrm{Ci}(x)$, but I'm using calculus 1 knowledge, any hint or help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the full expression (including the limit) that you get after the integration by parts? Can you see how this might be nicer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to compute the integral, you need only to show that the average is tending towards zero. Notice that

$$\left|\frac 1 x \int_0^x t \cos \frac 1 t \, dt\right| \le \frac 1 x \int_0^x t \, dt = \frac x 2 \to 0$$

as desired. Hence, the limit is zero.

P.S. Don't forget about the boundary terms when you integrate by parts. They're easy to deal with, but you still have to!

---

Also, just to be sure, here is a rough idea of why we could know the limit is zero in advance. The integral $\frac 1 x \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$ is the average of $f$ on $[0, x]$. If $f$ is oscillatory like $\sin 1 / t$ is, and spends an equal amount of time above and below the axis, the average is zero.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\sin(1/t)dt&=-x\cos(1/x)+\dfrac{2}{x}\int_{0}^{x}t\cos(1/t)dt\\
&=-x\cos(1/x)+2\cdot\eta_{x}\cos(1/\eta_{x}),
\end{align*}
by Integral Mean Value Theorem, now note that $0<\eta_{x}<x$ and hence $\eta_{x}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ and appeal to Squeeze Theorem to that $|\eta_{x}\cos(1/\eta_{x})|\leq\eta_{x}$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\displaystyle \forall a\in \mathrm{R}:\left| \sin{a} \right|\le 1\Rightarrow \forall t\in \mathrm{R-\displaystyle \left\{ 0 \right\}}:\left| \sin{\frac{1}{t}} \right|\le 1$$
$$\displaystyle  \int_{\varepsilon}^{t}\left| \sin{\frac{1}{t}} \right|dt\le \int_{\varepsilon}^{t}dt=t-\displaystyle \varepsilon\approx t:(t\gtrsim0 ,\varepsilon\approx 0)$$
$$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\left| \sin{\frac{1}{t}} \right|dt\le \lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\frac{t}{t}=1 $$